# How do you set the color palette so that it starts with the darkest color, where older data being lighter than current

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, color-palette

I'm plotting a correlation scatter plot, where my data frame has time data and the start year is arbitrary. In this case now I have the following `R` code

```
## Set seed for randomness in dummy data: ##
set.seed(123)

## Create data frame: ##
df.Data <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 650),
                      DE = rnorm(650, 2, 1), AT = rnorm(650, 5, 2))
corPearson <- cor.test(x = df.Data$DE, y = df.Data$AT, method = "pearson")

df.Data$year <- format(as.Date(df.Data$date), '%Y')
  
## PLOT: ##
p <- ggplot(data = df.Data, aes(x = DE, y = AT, group = 1)
      ) +
      geom_point(aes(color = year)) + 
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c") +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
      scale_colour_brewer(palette = 'Greens') + 
      xlab("PEGAS TTF M1") +
      ylab("EEX DEB M1") +
      ggtitle("Correlation Scatter Plot (Pearson)") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
    
    ## Correlation plot converting from ggplot to plotly: #
    CorrelationPlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

My problem lies in the color palette. I use the `Greens` color palette, which plots data from 2020 in a darker green than data from 2019, which I would like to keep as it is.

Nevertheless, I would like it to start with the darker shades of green, e.g. data from 2020 with the green of the red arrow, data from 2019 with the green of the blue arrow.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_color_manual` to set custom colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

## Set seed for randomness in dummy data: ##
set.seed(123)

## Create data frame: ##
df.Data <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 650),
                      DE = rnorm(650, 2, 1), AT = rnorm(650, 5, 2))
corPearson <- cor.test(x = df.Data$DE, y = df.Data$AT, method = "pearson")

df.Data$year <- format(as.Date(df.Data$date), '%Y')

## PLOT: ##
p <- ggplot(data = df.Data, aes(x = DE, y = AT, group = 1)
) +
  geom_point(aes(color = year)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(values=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Greens")[7:8])( length(unique(df.Data$year)) )) + 
  xlab(df.Data$DE) +
  ylab(df.Data$AT) +
  ggtitle("Correlation Scatter Plot (Pearson)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))

p

## Correlation plot converting from ggplot to plotly: #
CorrelationPlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you! I have defined now my own color scheme like this: ```scale_color_manual(values = c("#DCF1D5", "#B4DCAB", "#81C07A", "#419F44", "#007d3c")) ``` (fromn light to dark). If I have only data from 2019 and 2020, then the colors should be ```"#007d3c"``` for 2020 and  ```"#419F44"``` for 2019.

Comment: The time data is arbitrary, it could be also the case that I have data from 2016 to 2020. Then my own color palette should also work in the same way, namely ```"#007d3c"``` for 2020 and so on.... How can I do this?

Comment: Please see my edit. Now using `colorRampPalette` a custom palette is created based on the unique number of years available in the data.

Comment: Would it be possible to only use every second color? Because when I plot data from 2017 to 2020, it is very, very difficult for me to see a color difference between 2020 and 2019 (or 2016 and 2017)

Comment: You can simply set the starting color of the custom palette to a lighter green e.g. `scale_color_manual(values=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Greens")[c(3,8)])( length(unique(df.Data$year)) ))`. or use your colors directly: `scale_color_manual(values= tail(c("#DCF1D5", "#B4DCAB", "#81C07A", "#419F44", "#007d3c"), length(unique(df.Data$year))))`