# Color the current data points differently in the scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scatter-plot

My data tables can contain either daily data or weekly data from the year 2020. I create the scatter plot with the regression line as follows:

```
##########
## DAY: ##
##########
dt.day <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                     DE = rnorm(365, 4, 1), Austria = rnorm(365, 10, 2), 
                     Czechia = rnorm(365, 1, 2), check.names = FALSE)

## Linear regression: ##
regLine <- lm(DE ~ Austria, data = dt.day)

## PLOT: ##
p <- ggplot(data = dt.day, aes(x = Austria, y = DE, 
                               text = paste("Date: ", date, '\n',
                                            "Austria: ", Austria, "GWh/h", '\n',
                                            "DE: ", DE, "\u20ac/MWh"),
                               group = 1)
     ) +
     geom_point(color = "#419F44") +
     geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c") +
     theme_classic() +
     theme(legend.position = "none") +
     theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
     xlab("Austria") +
     ylab("DE")

# Correlation plot converting from ggplot to plotly: #
AUSTRIA <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")


###########
## WEEK: ##
###########
dt.week <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '7 day', length.out = 53),
                      Germany = rnorm(53, 4, 1), Austria = rnorm(53, 10, 2), 
                      Czechia = rnorm(53, 1, 2), check.names = FALSE)
```

The plot for the daily data looks like this:

[image]

I would like to plot the **last 10 days** of my data table (regardless of how much data it contains, because it could only be data from January to April every day) in a different color (`"#F07D00"`).
The plot for the weekly data table is plotted analogously. I would like to color differently the **last 4 weeks**.

I also have another question:

If I had a data table that had hourly entries every day (i.e. 24 per day), how would that work for the points for the **last 2 days**? The format of the 1st column (`date`) has the format `"POSIXct"` `"POSIXt"` as the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `library(lubridate)`. For the last 10 days:

```
 geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(date >= now()-days(10), "#F07D00", "#007d3c")))
```

Comment: This gives me blue points for the last 10 days and pink points for the remaining points.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is not setting the colors itself but only defines the groups by which to separate colors.  You could add `scale_color_manual(values = c("#F07D00", "#419F44")) +` to your plot to set your desired color values. In the ifelse call the labels of the groups ("last 10 days" vs. "older") could be set, for instance, if you want a legend.

Comment: @AndreasM ok thank you! Do you have any idea, how this could work with the weekly data (last 4 weeks colored differently) and the hourly data (last 2 days colored differently)? The last 4 weeks would be the last 4 entries / lines of the column.

Comment: There are also `hours()` and `weeks()`. As long as you have date objects this would would similarily.

Comment: @Michi - This is the same as I have pointed out to you [a month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151709/9841389).